# Fatal error when trying to submit exp:channel:form

Tags: safecracker, error, ee3, fatal

Trying to submit entries "outside" EE with the exp:channel:form, but when hitting the submit-button, it gives me

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /hsphere/local/home/distortedkid/bigsouth.se/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Core.php on line 539
```

The form-code/markup on the site is pretty complex, but even when I dumb it down to the super-duper basic example given by the EE docs, I still get the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Standup</title>
</head>
<body>
  {exp:channel:form channel="standup" return="contact/thanks" }
     <input name="title" type="text">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  {/exp:channel:form}
</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts?

Googling this issue hasn't really given me anything of value (or that I can understand).

Just updated form 2.7x to 3.0.6 flawlessly, if that could have anything to do with anything.

Comment: Works on clean install on local machine. So something went wrong during update or an old file ghosting.

Comment: Have you checked PHP versions on your server? I'm sure EE3 has good backwards compat, but check anyways. And that file at the `/legacy/` path didn't exist before you updated, so it won't be file ghosting.